# Unpredictable results when sending HTTP POST using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, json, post, httpresponse

I'm using `DefaultHttpClient` to send HTTP POST request containing json raw data:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost(post_url);

StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); // json is my JSONObject

se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"); 
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

httppostreq.setEntity(se);

HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);

String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
```

I'm using it to send like 5 requests, and the result must be a json-raw-response, although I'm getting the first two responses as predicted but the other three I'm getting a HTML code of a webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8"><title>WEB SERVICE</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/merge.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript"> ..... till the end of the webpage
```

So, what can lead me to this result and what can be wrong in my work?

Comment: I'm willing to bet that's a spam / wrong request / other error message your webserver / appserver / whateverserver is trying to display to the client.

Comment: @SBI you mean I'm sending post request the wrong way or the server handles it the wrong way ?

Comment: I can only guess. Take a look at the whole message, check the response code and header, check the server log, debug the server code. Whatever you have access to. From the fact that you get proper responses first and then fail to get them, my best guess is flood protection. However, it could also be that the later calls are malformed.